# Apache Camel https with client certificate

Tags: java, ssl, apache-camel, client-certificates

I am building a client application with Apache Camel for an https REST endpoint which is protected by client authentication (i.e. requires a certificate on the client to connect to the server)

Got a right pkcs12 certificate, imported it into the keychain and now can open the REST endpoint url in Chrome

Imported the same pkcs12 certificate into `cacerts` with `keytool -importkeystore`. That should import both public and private keys from what I understand.

Now, camel "https://..." route throws an error `sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target`

I don't really understand why I would have to explicitly configure SSLContextParameters with the path to `cacerts` as described in [Camel HTTP component docs](http://camel.apache.org/http.html) (wouldn't `cacerts` be loaded automatically?) but I did it anyway - same error.

It's a self-signed certificate, would that be the reason? How can I debug it further?

Camel version is 2.16.1

Comment: How have you configured your SSL context parameters? And any reason you're not using http4 component?

Comment: http4 is more difficult with Websphere 8.5 but if that solves my problem I would use http4 for sure. Tried http - doesn't change anything. Will post my SSL Context configuration in the question in a minute